# Parser for Propositional Logic

Tags: parsing, logic, bison, yacc

When I run *bison -d myfile.y* it gives the following error: *bison: m4: Invalid argument*. I think the problem is operator precedence but still I can't resolve the problem. The *Make** functions create propositional logic expressions.

yacc file:

```
%{
#include "global.h"
#include "PLResolution.h"
%}

%token END
%token LEFT_PAREN RIGHT_PAREN
%token BICOND
%token FORWARD_IMPLIC BACKWARD_IMPLIC 
%token OR
%token AND
%token NOT 
%token identifier

%left BICOND
%left BACKWARD_IMPLIC
%left FORWARD_IMPLIC
%left OR
%left AND
%left NOT

%start Input
%%
Input:
/* Empty */
| Input Line
;
Line:
END
| Sentence END
;
Sentence:
AtomicSentence
| ComplexSentence
;
AtomicSentence:
identifier {$$=MakeAtomicSentence($1);}
;
ComplexSentence:
LEFT_PAREN Sentence RIGHT_PAREN
| NOT Sentence {$$=MakeNotSentence($1);}
| Sentence AND Sentence {$$=MakeAndSentence($1, $2);}
| Sentence OR Sentence {$$=MakeOrSentence($1, $2);}
| Sentence FORWARD_IMPLIC Sentence {$$=MakeForwardIMPLIC($1, $2);}
| Sentence BACKWARD_IMPLIC Sentence {$$=MakeBackwardIMPLIC($1, $2);}
| Sentence BICOND Sentence {$$=MakeBICOND($1, $2);}
;
%%
int yyerror(char *s) {
    printf("%s\n",s);
}
int main(void) {
    yyparse()
}
```

Comment: This works fine on my machine.  Which platform are you using bison on, and which version of bison?

Comment: @Gian Thank you for the reply; I am running bison 2.4.1 on Windows Vista. Could you send me the generated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated code on my platform is unlikely to work for you.  However, I found [this link](http://venublog.com/2010/02/07/changing-mysql-parser-code-on-windows-build-breaks-due-to-bison/) which describes similar problems other people have had on Vista with bison and m4.  Perhaps the suggested fix will work for you too?  It seems to involve copying the m4 binary to the local directory.

EDIT: and just in case you don't get it to work, I've uploaded the two generated files for you:  [prop.tab.cc](http://expdev.net/prop.tab.cc) [prop.tab.hh](http://expdev.net/prop.tab.hh).  Not sure if they will work at all, but maybe it'll help.

Comment: I guess so.  It depends what exactly you want to achieve.  Did you want differentiated levels of precedence, for example?